# Differences between dynamic window managers?

Tags: window-manager, xmonad, awesome-wm

Dynamic window managers support both tiling and floating window layout. There are quite a few of them, e.g. [awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/), [dwm](http://dwm.suckless.org/), [catwm](https://github.com/pyknite/catwm), [xmonad](http://xmonad.org/) and probably many more. A lot of them claim to be stable, fast and with a small footprint. They seem to be aimed at powerusers and require a but of configuration work to get them working to your liking. But what are the important differences between them? How would I go about choosing one, given that the time required to learn each of them prevents me from giving them a fair test?

Comment: Nothing is less likely to have bugs than a program written in Haskell and the high configureability of XMonad is part of its charm.